# Find the x-coordinate as the chord of two points on a parabola touches the x-axis

Tags: geometry

> The chord joining the points $P(ap^2,2ap)$ and $Q(aq^2,2aq)$ on the parabola $y^2=4ax$ has the equation $(p+q)y = 2x + 2apq$. A variable chord $PQ$ of the parabola is such that the lines $OP$ and $OQ$ are perpendicular, where $O$ is the origin. Prove that the chord $PQ$ cuts the axis of $x$ at a fixed point, and give the $x$-coordinate of this point. Also find the equation of the locus of the mid-point of $PQ$.

I've managed to prove the chord equation, but I don't understand why the $x$-coordinate of $PQ$ touching the $x$-axis is $4a$ rather than $-apq%$. That would mean $pq=-4$, but I don't know how that's equated. The locus of the mid-point of $PQ$ is apparently $y^2 =2ax-8a^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of $OP, m_{OP}=\dfrac{2ap-0}{ap^2-0}=\dfrac2p$

Similarly, $m_{OQ}=\dfrac2q$

Now $OP\perp OQ\iff m_{OP}\cdot m_{OQ}=-1$

Hope you can take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! Could I ask for another favour since you're a good teacher. I'm trying to prove $\tan \theta = \frac{m_1 - m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$ using vector methods in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992224/proving-tan-theta-fracm-1-m-21m-1m-2-using-vector-methods), but I'm stuck - can you help?