# Proving $\tan \theta = \frac{m_1 - m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$ using vector methods

Tags: vectors

> Two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ lie in the $x$-$y$ plane and have cartesian equations $y=m_1x+c_1$ and $y=m_2x+c_2$ respectively. Use vector methods to show that if $\theta$ is the angle between $L_1$ and $L_2$ then:
>   $$
> \tan \theta = \frac{m_1 - m_2}{1+m_1m_2}
> $$

Letting $u = i+m_1j$ and $v=i+m_2j$:

$$
u\cdot v = |u|\space|v|\space\cos\theta \\
1+m_1m_2 = \sqrt{1^2 + m_1^2}\sqrt{1^2+m_2^2}\cos\theta \\
\cos\theta = \frac{1+m_1m_2}{1+m_1+m_2+m_1m_2} 
$$

How can I get $\tan\theta$ out of it?

Comment: $\sqrt{1 + m_1^2}\sqrt{1 + m_2^2} \ne 1 + m_1 + m_2 + m_1 m_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid later complications, I will assume $m_1>m_2$. If this is not the case, then I can swap the labels of the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$; this flips the sign of both $\tan\theta$ and of $m_1-m_2$, and thus leaves the formula invariant. So I can assume as above without loss of generality.

As noted in the OP, we have the dot product identity $u\cdot v=|u||v|\cos\theta$. But we also have the cross product identity $u\times v = (|u||v|\sin\theta)\hat{n}$ where $\hat{n}$ is the unit direction vector determined by the right-hand rule (e.g. $i\times j=k=\hat{n}$).

Direct algebra then gives $\tan\theta= \dfrac{(u\times v)\cdot \hat{n}}{u \cdot v}=\dfrac{m_2-m_1}{1+m_1m_2}(\hat{z}\cdot \hat{n}).$ Since $m_1>m_2$ by assumption, we have $\hat{n}=-k$ by the RH rule. We therefore pick up a minus from the dot product, verifying the desired identity.

Comment: Thanks. What are $\hat{z}$ and $\hat{n}$?

Comment: @hohner: $\hat{z}$ should be $k$ (unit vector pointing along positive $z$-axis); I'll amend that. $\hat{n}$ is the (unit) direction vector implied by the RH-rule for cross products.

Comment: @hohner: Edited, hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\tan (a-b) = \frac{\tan a - \tan b}{1+\tan a\tan b}
$$

Comment: How do I turn $\cos\theta$ into $\tan(a-b)$? I'm using that $a=m_1$ and $b=m_2$?

Comment: Do you have any advice that can help? :)

Comment: consider the angle $0x, m_1$ and $Ox, m2$. You are looking for the $\tan$ of their difference. And what is the $\tan$ of these angles?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by $0x,m1$ and $Ox,m2$. Would you mind adding a few more steps so it's explicit?

Comment: Ox, m1  is the angle between the x-axis  and the vector m1!

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry. I don't see how using $\tan(a-b)$ involves vector methods, though.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, but that's no need to downvote now is it? :) All I want to know is how what you suggested links to vector methods, since that's what the question is all about...

Comment: I did not downvote.